# RoR MongoID Lookup doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new to MongoID ( & mongoDB) and having issue with performance due to pulling data from a reference collection.

```
class Accounting::Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :contact, :class_name => 'Contact'
End

 class Contact
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :name, type: String
 end
```

Also using gem 'kaminari-mongoid' for paging.

Simplified version of my query is:

```
@invoices = Accounting::Invoice.all.page(params[:page].to_i)

<% @invoices.each do |inv| %>
   <% inv.contact.name %>
<% end %>
```

Issue is when I display the data, to simply get the name from Contact collection, I have to re-connect to DB and pull the name for each listing. I tried using $lookup, however when I do that paging with kaminari doesn't work...

Any suggestions on how to get the contact name without needing to re-connect to database?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean _re-connect to DB_?

Comment: Basically for each inv.contact.name, it connects back to server to get the name from Contact. So if I have 50 invoices to display, my Im making 51 queries in total. 1 for the original data, list of invoices. 50 for each Contact.name

Comment: Try `Accounting::Invoice.includes(:contact).page(params[:page].to_i)`

Comment: As further read up to @JagdeepSingh suggestion: https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/09/faster-rails-eliminating-n-plus-one-queries.html

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, Thank you it worked great!
Is there a way I can integrate "only" with the referenced collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are experiencing is [N + 1 queries problem](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). You can reduce the number of queries to 2 by using [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) for an association. In your case:

```
Accounting::Invoice.includes(:contact)
                   .page(params[:page].to_i)
```

should do the trick.

As it returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, you can chain other scopes and methods which apply to Arels. So, if you want to use `only` with this, do it as:

```
Accounting::Invoice.includes(:contact)
                   .only(<list_of_attributes>)
                   .page(params[:page].to_i)
```